Is it clear what the chart means by 'good excuse for a change'?
Is it clear what the bar graph means by "good excuse for a change"? Does it mean that attending the training is a good excuse for a change of their typical work?

Roughly the same number of managers and secretaries think that the
training courses are a good excuse for a change of their typical work.



It means, they see the course as a way of getting out of doing their normal work for a time.

Thanks for the comment. But I don't know that. So for native speakers, there is no ambiguity?

A good excuse for a change from their typical work.

The chart looks like a complete waste of time - whoever produced it can't even spell waste or valuable, so I wouldn't waste my time trying to guess what they think good excuse for a change might mean, or why they chose that particular phrasing.

The labels on the graph have several typos:

Waste of valuable time ("valuable" is probably unnecessary)

Important for the job

Good for networking

Good excuse for a change


The latter means that it adds variety to their work. It's a chance to do something different instead of the same thing they do every day.

Frankly nothing is clear about this bar graph. But the least clear thing is the phrase "good excuse for a change."
A reasonable bit of guesswork and common sense suggests that it means "the training makes a nice change (from the everyday routine)." But it gets confusing because, when talking about jobs, "a change" often means "a change of job," as in "I've been working here for five years and I think it's time for a change." There's more than a shadow of a doubt that the phrase could mean "this training is so unpleasant (or the employee's adherence to it is so low) that it provides a good excuse to terminate employment."
Similar "reasonable guesswork" is needed to establish that "Office worker's" should be plural, as should the legend labels "manager" and "secretary" (unless only two people were surveyed, and the percentages indicate the strength of their feelings?), that "wast" means "waste," that "valueable" means "valuable," that "net working" means "networking," and that the x-axis is capped at 90% to make the differences look bigger and not for any better reason.
